# WordPress action to listen to external webhooks

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set up a Epos Now webhook to trigger an action on my woo commerce site but having no luck. Struggling to get my head around how this works.

This is what I’m looking to achieve (or so I think this is how it would work)

- EPOS web hook sends a http post request to a URL
- This URL receives request and gets the raw body data
- Wordpress action check URLs for new requests, pulls the data from the URL and then I can manipulate the data from there.

I’ve used [https://requestbin.fullcontact.com](https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/)/ and all the information is there. I can see the headers and the raw body data is there returning the JSON string of data I want.

But for the life of me I cannot recreate this on my own URL.

The Epos Now back end has a queue of web hooks. It shows that my web hook has been sent to my URL and returns a 200 so it’s transmitted successfully. I know I’ll have to code something up on my URL end to get this data but I’m struggling to make it happen.

The Epos Now docs say I need to parse headers

> "WebHooks are sent to your end-point as HTTP POST requests. At your end-point, there are some HTTP headers which you should parse in order to understand the data. These are:"

I’ve tried to do this via the php manual example:

```
<?php
$headers = "content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n".
  "Server: Funky/1.0\r\n".
  "Set-Cookie: foo=bar\r\n".
  "Set-Cookie: baz=quux\r\n".
  "Folded: works\r\n\ttoo\r\n";
print_r(http_parse_headers($headers));
?>
```

And tried to pull content via:

```
<?php
    $result = file_get_contents('URL here');
   echo $result;
?>
or using php://input
```

I’ve tried so many lines of code but nothing has worked. I feel like I’m missing something, probably something that’s really obvious and totally noobish but this is the most complicated thing I’ve worked on lol. I feel like I’ve not understood how these API’s connect to each other and therefore trying to do something which isn’t the right way maybe?

If someone could please shed some light onto where I’m going wrong or what I’m missing that would be much appreciated. I've been researching for days!